# How to read all bytes from file

Tags: c

im trying to read all bytes from a file to a buffer but when i encounter NULL it stops and returns the wrong amount of bytes. How should i approach this?

thanks in advance

Below is my code:

```
FILE *fp;
unsigned char *buffer = NULL;
size_t len;

fp = fopen(input_file, "rb+");
if (fp == NULL)  
{
 // abort if file cannot be opened
 printf("Cannot open file");
 exit(-1);
}
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
buffer = malloc(len + 1);
if (NULL == buffer)
{
    // Handle malloc failure & exit
    exit(-1);
}

if (fread(buffer, 1, len, fp))
{
    fclose(fp);
    //buffer[len] = '\0';
    //printf("%s",buffer);
    //printf("%ld",len);

    return buffer;

    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
}
else
{
    //Handle fread failure & exit
    exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* declare a file pointer */
FILE    *infile;
char    *buffer;
long    numbytes;
 
/* open an existing file for reading */
infile = fopen("test.rib", "r");
 
/* quit if the file does not exist */
if(infile == NULL)
    return 1;
 
/* Get the number of bytes */
fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_END);
numbytes = ftell(infile);
 
/* reset the file position indicator to 
the beginning of the file */
fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_SET);    
 
/* grab sufficient memory for the 
buffer to hold the text */
buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char)); 
 
/* memory error */
if(buffer == NULL)
    return 1;
 
/* copy all the text into the buffer */
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, infile);
fclose(infile);
 
/* confirm we have read the file by
outputing it to the console */

/*
optional - remarked

printf("The file called test.dat contains this text\n\n%s", buffer);
*/

 
/* free the memory we used for the buffer */
free(buffer);
```

Comment: I'd recommend "malloc()" instead of "calloc()" - but your reply is spot-on:  1) [fopen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), 2) Get filesize: [fseek()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek), 3) allocate buffer: [malloc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) (or "calloc()", if you really think you need to initialize the buffer), 4) read all bytes at once: [fread()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread).  PS: I'd also recommend [perror()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) or equivalent, to display a meaningful error message, if "fopen()" fails>  Rather than silently returning "1".

Comment: ive tested this and it doesnt work... the thing is that in the file i have encrypted bytes as HEX values. So when it reads 00 from the file it thinks that the fread is over.

Comment: But i want it to continue until there is nothing to read, not until the 00.

Comment: @gsoap: You're mistaken.  Ken Lee's suggestion *SHOULD* read the entire file.  Look at the documentation I cited.  fread() just reads bytes from a file ... provided the file has data.  SUGGESTION: `fopen("test.rib", "rb");`, "rb" to ensure it's opened as a BINARY file?

Comment: For binary file, please use fopen("test.rib", "rb") instead of fopen("test.rib", "r");

Comment: @Ken Lee: `rb` is my suggestion, too.  This is necessary if the binary file has embedded linefeeds.  HOWEVER - gsoap's belief that fread() "stops at null" ... is nonsense.  I'm not at all sure why he thinks that is happening :(

Comment: i think that fread stops because i test my code and there is no other point why that should happen..

Comment: You haven't shown us complete code (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), nor shown any sample data.  HOWEVER: 1) fread does NOT stop at "nulls".  2) Consequently, fread DOES read nulls.  3) So if you're returning the (complete!) buffer as a "string" ... and the buffer happens to contain embedded "nulls" ... well then yeah - the client's first read of the first string still stop at the first null ;)  That doesn't mean that fread "failed".  It just means you need to parse your buffer differently :)

Comment: @paulsm4 You are righ. I should check how thoroughly how i process the buffer